# Visual studio 2010 Code definition window with Resharper 6

Tags: visual-studio, resharper

I installed Resharper 6 with VS 2010. But whenever I press <kbd>F12</kbd> for a type, it goes to metadataviewer, which Resharper provides. I want to use Code Definition Window instead. Is there a way to set it up.

Comment: Sorry, still don't know which screens you're referring to. Screenshots of "from here I want to go to here" would help.

Comment: There's no way to set ReSharper up to show target code in the Code Definition Window. Does it feel any better than, say, opening sources reconstructed from PDB in the text editor?

Comment: Thanks gorohoroh. I think so, just wanted to get an official thing. Do you know if R# have any plan to fix this. Because the Code Definition Window is far better than metadataviewer and object Browser, and source code, which R# should allow to add a custom command. Still not good enough.

Comment: @Pingpong No such plans that I'm aware of. To be honest, I don't quite understand the value of CDW. Can you enlighten me? As far as I can see it's just a pinned non-editable text editor-like tab.